# Hide dropdown - Sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I've tried searching for this but nothing works so far.

I'm looking to hide a dropdown that appears whenever I press space or finish a tag. When I try to go to the new line it enters an `<a>` tag instead of going to a new line. If I press SHIFT+ENTER it works though but I just want to disable it altogether.

This is the dropdown:
[image]

I have tried using these settings which I've found from various other Stack Overflow posts:

```
"auto_complete": false,
"tab_completion": false,
"auto_close_tags": false,
"disable_completions": true
```

But nothing removes it.

Is there another command I should be trying here?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't happen when using [Sublime Text 3](https://sublimetext.com/3). Try upgrading and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 8 days I have found the answer.

Add

```
"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
```

To your user settings file. Instead of hiding it, this will change the hotkey from `ENTER/RETURN` to `TAB`. This also works on ST3.